# How can i resolve this error?C#

Tags: c#

i have a private method is ball.cs class in witch i want to modify a bool type from margins.cs class, but i get the Error   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PingPong.Margins.win'.
Can someone help me with this?

this is the ball class code :

```
namespace PingPong
{
 public class Ball
{

     private PictureBox ball;
     Random rand= new Random();
     Player leftSidePlayer, rightSidePlayer;

     int xSpeed, ySpeed;

     public Ball(PictureBox aBall, Player leftSidePlayer, Player rightSidePlayer)
     {   

         this.ball = aBall;
         this.leftSidePlayer = leftSidePlayer;
         this.rightSidePlayer = rightSidePlayer;
         xSpeed = 1;
         ySpeed = 2;
         resetBall();
     } 

     internal void processmove()
     {
         var bottom = Margins.bottomOfWorld - ball.Height;
         DoMove();

         if(ball.Location.Y >= bottom || ball.Location.Y <= Margins.topOfWorld)
         {
             ySpeed *= -1;
         }

         if (ball.Location.X <= Margins.leftOfWorld)
         {
            Score(leftSidePlayer);
         }
         else if (ball.Location.X >= Margins.rightOfWorld - ball.Width) 
         {
             Score(rightSidePlayer); 
         }

         if ((leftSidePlayer.paddle.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ball.Bounds)) || (rightSidePlayer.paddle.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ball.Bounds)))
         {
             xSpeed *= -1;
             if ((ySpeed <= 6 && ySpeed >=-6) && (xSpeed <= 5 && xSpeed >=-5) )
             {
                 if(ySpeed < 0)
                 {
                     ySpeed -= 1;
                 }else
                 {
                     ySpeed += 1;
                 } 

                 if (xSpeed < 0)
                 {
                     xSpeed -= 1;

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     xSpeed += 1;
                 }
             }
         }


     }

     private int DoMove()
     {
         var bottom = Margins.bottomOfWorld - ball.Height;
         ball.Location = new Point(ball.Location.X + xSpeed, Math.Max(Margins.topOfWorld, Math.Min(bottom, ball.Location.Y + ySpeed)));
         return bottom;
     }

     private void Score(Player winningPlayer)
     {
         winningPlayer.scoreNumber++;

         if(winningPlayer.scoreNumber == 7)
         {
             if(winningPlayer == leftSidePlayer  )
             {
                 Margins.win = true;
             }else if(winningPlayer == rightSidePlayer)
             {
                 Margins.win = false;
             }


         }


         resetBall();
     }

     private void resetBall()
     {
         ball.Location = new Point((Margins.leftOfWorld + Margins.rightOfWorld) / 2, (Margins.bottomOfWorld + Margins.topOfWorld) / 2);
         do
         {
             xSpeed = rand.Next(-3, 3);
             ySpeed = rand.Next(-3, 3);
         } while(Math.Abs(xSpeed) + Math.Abs(ySpeed) <= 3);

    }

}
```

}

and this is the margins class code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PingPong
{
    public class Margins
    {   //Marimea ferestrei 1000; 600
        public const int topOfWorld = 0, bottomOfWorld = 560, leftOfWorld =0, rightOfWorld = 1000;
        public bool? win = null;
    }
}
```

the error i get is in private void score when i use the margins.win = true
and margins.win = false .

Comment: Most c# errors you come across you can just search for on google and you'll find a stackoverflow question that should help. if it doesn't you should include your research in your own question

Comment: You trying to edit it like it static variable but it not, if you need it to be static make it static public static bool? win = null;

Comment: In addition to this being a duplicate, please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on writing a good question. In particular, try to come up with a [mcve] - most of the code in this question isn't relevant.

Comment: https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=An+object+reference+is+required+for+the+non-static+field&oq=An+object+reference+is+required+for+the+non-static+field&aqs=chrome..69i57.629j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a class with some static (or constant) variables now. Next to that, there is the instance variable `win`. That means you have to create an instance of `Margins` in order to get or set it.

If you really need a static class since there can always be just one `Margins` instance, make the class and its variables static:

```
public static class Margins
{   //Marimea ferestrei 1000; 600
    public const int topOfWorld = 0, bottomOfWorld = 560, leftOfWorld =0, rightOfWorld = 1000;
    public static bool? win = null;
}
```

If not, make a proper instance of `Margins`:

```
private Margins margins = new Margins();

this.margins.win = true;
```